# Read through huge text files and store each line in database

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a PHP script which runs through a text file (actually it's a 'list' file from imdb) and stores it on my local MySQL database.

```
public static function updateMovies( $list ) {
    $offset = 15;               // movies.list start with movie names at line 16
    $handle = fopen($list, "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
    if ($handle) {
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $buffer = fgets($handle);
            if($offset!=0)
                $offset--;
            else
                if($buffer[0] != '"'){
                    $title = trim( substr( $buffer, 0, strpos( $buffer, '(' ) ) );
                    $year = intval(trim( substr( $buffer, strpos( $buffer,'(' )+1, 4 ) ));
                    Movie::create( $title, $year );
                }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Since those list-files are up to 200MB it takes a lot of time. By Default PHP's `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` is set to 30 seconds.

I set this value to 300 just to try if it works. For example, my 'movies.list' file is around 80MB and using this script for 300 seconds created around 25000 lines in my database. This doesn't work because I have not even reached the movies starting with 'B'.

I know I can set the `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` to 0 (unlimited) but in the future I don't want this database to be on my localhost. I want it on my webserver and my webserver hosts `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` is set to 90 as far as I know.

Any ideas how you would handle this?

Comment: Don't do it through http, but use a command line script

Comment: Don't do individual inserts. You'll spent a LOT of time on database overhead. Use mysql's multi-insert to cut that a bit: `insert into table (...) values (...), (...), (...), etc...`.

Comment: is this a csv or tab-delimited file? it might be a lot faster to use mysql on the cli to infile the data into a loading table and then run various updates on each column that you want to modify, or transform the data in other ways.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried to tweak my script for example i didnt use prepared statements. and got a little more speed out of it by making an array of 1000 movies, pushing it to the database, clear the array and move on with the use of set_time_limit betweens these actions...it perfomed "okay" but stopped after inserting around 200.000 rows...now i just wrote a little java tool which works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may either: 
Use [set_time_limit(sec)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)
or (better) run your script from the [command line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) through a cron entry. That way you will avoid many other non-php related timeout issues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its a goo idea for you to load such kind of large file directly to your database ... especially when it takes so long to conclude

**My Advice**

Split the files to smaller chunks locally .. then on the remote server upload it to your database

Example (Documentation :  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_%28Unix%29 )

```
 exec('split -d -b 2048m ' . $list . ' chunks');
```

For a pure PHP implementation see

http://www.php.happycodings.com/File_Manipulation/code50.html

Or

```
define('CHUNK_SIZE', 1024*1024);
function readfile_chunked($filename, $retbytes = TRUE) {
    $buffer = '';
    $cnt =0;
    // $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    if ($handle === false) {
      return false;
    }
    while (!feof($handle)) {
      $buffer = fread($handle, CHUNK_SIZE);
      echo $buffer;
      ob_flush();
      flush();
      if ($retbytes) {
        $cnt += strlen($buffer);
      }
    }
    $status = fclose($handle);
    if ($retbytes && $status) {
      return $cnt; // return num. bytes delivered like readfile() does.
    }
    return $status;
  }
```