# PHP upload limit and cURL

Tags: php, apache, curl, upload, amazon-s3

I'm using a shared hosting with 2MB limit for uploading file using php. So I was wondering if I upload a file more than 2MB using cURL to my S3 amazon , will it work ? 
Thanks

Comment: how will you get the file to your server so it can upload to amazon?

Comment: Don't think it will work because the file will have to be uploaded to your temp-folder first...

Comment: @Baba How do I split the file in php ?

Comment: Since you say you want to use curl to upload to your server  ??? you can split the file and sent it in batches ...

Comment: If you are only allowed to use 2MB it would be a good moment to start looking for another host

Comment: I agree with PeeHaa .... but if you have no choice then split the file .... if that you need let me know

Comment: how to split the file ? any tutorial or document ? @Baba

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406300/split-big-txt-file-with-php/12407208#12407208 ... what format are the files ???

Comment: @Baba Thanks for the link, file are mostly in zip or image file.

Comment: @user1725155 that is easy .... if you still need help let me know  ....

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434) out.

This way you can completely avoid uploading the file through your webserver, meaning no max-size issues and less workload. You only have to specify the callback URL and you're done.