# File is too large I can't get input to my php program

Tags: php, file, file-io

I'd like to get input from txt file but the file contain data 1.6 GB. So it crashed when I load the data into my variable how can I get it in my php program

Comment: So load a line from the file, process it, read the next line, process that, read the next, etc.... don't try to load it all in one go

Comment: Why are you trying to process this file in PHP? Y...you're not actually trying to display 1.6GB of data in a web page, right? **Right?**

Comment: @MarkBaker - make your comment an answer. It's the right one.

Comment: he didn't say he's using it for web page. and those 1.6GB data could be in one line.

Comment: @su- - No, he didn't. But I'm not sure why anyone would use PHP for anything other than web development, since that's what the language was built for.

Comment: people use php for scripting too

Comment: @Jack - I do a lot of non-web stuff in PHP, and it's perfectly capable of doing that as well

Comment: @JackManey That's the kind of assumption that make me comfortable closing this question. Not enough details.

Comment: You can split the files into chunks if you are working with csv or log files http://stackoverflow.com/a/10271542/1226894

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process it line per line :

```
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        // Process here..
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = fopen($filename);
while ($line = fgets($file)) {
    // do stuff
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: This is work!! but I make twitter application and it error showed that "error too many request" how can I manage it?'